# Latex: Changing nodes name using Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Please, how do I change nodes name? I want to change my nodes from a,b,c,d,e to v1, v2, v3, v4 and v5 (please note that the numbers beside V must be subscript). Here is my latex Tikz

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


 \begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
            thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (a) {a};
  \node[main node] (b) [below left of=a] {b};
  \node[main node] (c) [below right of=a] {c};
   \node[main node] (d)  [below of=b]{d};
   \node[main node] (e)  [below of=c]{e};

  \path
(a) [-]edge [loop above] node {} (a)
     [-]edge node[below] {} (b)
     [->]edge node [below]{} (c)
    [->] edge node [right]{} (d)
    [-] edge node [right]{} (e)

(b)    [-]edge [loop left] node {} (b)
       [-]edge node[below] {} (a)
        [->] edge node [right]{} (c)
        [-] edge node [right]{} (d)

(c) [-]edge [loop right] node {} (c)

(d) [-]edge [loop below] node {} (d)
    [->]edge node[below] {} (c)
    [-]edge node[right] {} (b)

(e) [-]edge [loop below] node {} (e)
    [-]edge node[below] {} (a)
    [->]edge node[right] {} (b)
    [->]edge node[below] {} (c)
    [->] edge node [right]{} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: From an expression like `node (a) {b}`, `a` is the name which is used for reference and `b` is what is printed as node contents.  There is no relation between one and the other, you can print whatever you want as contents: `\node (a) {$v_1$}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `\node[main node] (a) {a};` to `\node[main node] (a) {$v_1$};` and so on.